# How can I combine two json arrays with axios React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I would like to get data with axios React from Laravel.But I didn' t success at combining two arrays by Ids. I return to informations of  product data and images from laravel Controller. Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

index.js

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/product`, {})
    .then((res) => {
      let allProducts = res.data.data;
      let productImages = res.data.images;

      allProducts = allProducts.filter((item) => 
        item.id == productImages.products_id
      )

      console.log('taks: ', allProducts)        
    })
    .catch(e => { console.log(e); })
}, []);
```

indexController.php

```php
public function index()
    {
        $data = Product::select(
            'products.id as id', 'products.title as title', 'products.price as price', 'products.description as description'
        )->get();

        $images = ProductsImage::select(
            'products_images.id as images_id', 'products_images.products_id as products_id', 'products_images.image as image_path'
        )->get();

        return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
            'data'=>$data,
            'images'=>$images
        ]);
}
```

Comment: where is the logic for combining two arrays

Comment: You may define a relation on your corresponding model. And may eager load the relation as well. This will return you a nested json as well.

Comment: You should use Laravel [relationships and eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to return your data in the desired structure direct from your API controller function.

Answer (score 0):

I changed indexController and models like below. And I can access to
products with images..

indexController.php

```html
public function index()
{
        $products = Product::with('images')->get();;
       
        return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
            'data'=>$products
        ]);
}
```

Model / ProductsImage.php

```html
class ProductsImage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['products_id', 'image'];

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'products_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Model / Product.php

```html
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'title', 'price', 'description'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductsImage::class, 'products_id', 'id');
    }
}
```